# How Can I make an Infinite Carousel JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, carousel, infinite

I am trying to make an infinite carousel using JQuery, the problem is when I go to the final image it just goes to a white screen, the fix for this is going back to the previous image, I know this is because each image is under one another but how can I make it loop so that it goes to the first image once I click next, or at least go back to the previous image?

```js
var sliderList;
$(function() {

  var sliderWrapper = $("#slider");
  sliderList = sliderWrapper.children("ul");
  var sliderItems = sliderList.children("li");

  function animateSlider(direction, duration) {
    if (direction === "+") {
      sliderList.animate({
        "margin-left": "+=800px"
      }, duration);
    } else if (direction === "-") {
      sliderList.animate({
        "margin-left": "-=800px"
      }, duration);
    }
  }

  $(".button").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("back")) {
      animateSlider("+", 1000);
    } else {
      animateSlider("-", 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/room1.jpg" alt="hotel room" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/room2.jpg" alt="hotel room" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/room3.jpg" alt="hotel room" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/room4.jpg" alt="hotel room" /></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you to include proper images (lorem pixel) and the CSS needed - you will likely have to see if margin-left is 0 and you are left direction, set to 800*4 and when 800*4 going right, set to 0

Answer (score 0):

Do a check to see if the sliderItem is the last item of the list then make the animate to 0 or the end depending on + or -

```
$(function() {

  var sliderWrapper = $("#slider");
  sliderList = sliderWrapper.children("ul");
  var sliderItems = sliderList.children("li");
  var count = 0;

  function animateSlider(direction, duration) {
    if (direction === "+") {
       if(sliderItems.length === count){
         sliderList.animate({
        "margin-left": "-=2400px"//go back to original 
      }, duration);
       }else{
          sliderList.animate({
          "margin-left": "+=800px"
          }, duration);
        }
       count++;
     }
```

something like that. Then just do the opposite for back